# Send data from java to javascript in format json

Tags: javascript, java, json

I have some data

```
@Override
     public String toString() {
          return
               "{" +
                    "id:" + id +
                    ", title:'" + title + '\'' +
               "}";
     }
```

I need to convert in JSON for javascript. The data must return key and value which I can display in a document.
I tried to use the method JSON.stringify and JSON.parse, but it converts in a string.

Comment: The java part is not ok. It does not output quotes for properties.

Comment: You need to create a valid JSON string, your's is not valid

Comment: @spi, you're right

Comment: It also doesn't output quotes for keys @spi

Comment: JSON.parse needs double quotes for string properties, your title property value is wrapped in single quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build and print your JSON by hand but you'll probably want to use SimpleJSON, Jackson 2 or GSON which will suit you better as the data gets more complex:

SimpleJSON:  https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple , [JAR](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjsonsimple111jar.htm)

GSON: https://github.com/google/gson , [JAR](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.6.2/)

```
//Simple JSON
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

//GSON
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;


public class JSONExamples {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String id = "123";
        String title = "Very Important Record";


        //Simple JSON
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("id", id);
        obj.put("title", title);
        System.out.println(obj);


        //GSON
        MyRecord myImportantRecord = new MyRecord(id, title);
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        gson.toJson(myImportantRecord, System.out);

    }

}
```

MyRecord.java:

```
public class MyRecord {
    private String id;
    private String title;
    MyRecord(String id, String title) {
        this.id=id;
        this.title=title;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From Java you can receive `stringified JSON` and you can parse it using `JSON.parse()` on javascript side to have it as a regular object.

1. Using [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) to convert Java object to JSON.

   ```
   Gson gson = new Gson();
   Staff obj = new Staff();
   //Java object to JSON, and assign to a String
   String jsonInString = gson.toJson(obj);
   ```
2. JavaScript Side

   ```
   var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
   ```